# ViroARSceneNavigator/ViroVRSceneNavigator from SideMenu based app

Tags: react-native, navigation, augmented-reality, react-navigation

Currently I'm working on an application which has side menu and there are list of mix of different types of scene like ARScenes, VRScenes and normal scenes like List, contact us, about us.

This is how I have created app structure.

Any sample would be great.

```
const Drawer = DrawerNavigator(
{
 Home: { screen: Home },
 SignUpScreen : {screen: SignUpScreen},
 HelloWorldScene : {screen: HelloWorldScene},
 HelloWorldSceneAR : {screen: HelloWorldSceneAR}
},
{
initialRouteName: "Home",
contentOptions: {
  activeTintColor: "#e91e63"
},
contentComponent: props => <SideBar {...props} />
});

const AppNavigator = StackNavigator(
{
Drawer: { screen: Drawer },
SignUpScreen : {screen: SignUpScreen},
HelloWorldScene : {screen: HelloWorldScene},
HelloWorldSceneAR : {screen: HelloWorldSceneAR},
},
{
initialRouteName: "Drawer",
headerMode: "none"
});

export default () =>
<Root>
 <AppNavigator />
</Root>;
```